# PowerShell 4.0 Add-Printer

Tags: powershell, printing, scripting, powershell-3.0, printers

I've just installed PowerShell 4.0 on my Win7 SP1 box, (up from the 2.0 native version). 
PowerShell 3.0 was supposed to have included a bunch of handy printer-specific functions such as Add-Printer, Add-PrinterDriver, etc., but running a 'Get-Command' on my box doesn't show any of the commands I'm looking for.

Do I have to install PowerShell 3.0 to get them?

Comment: Docs seem to say it only works on Windows 8.1 and server 2012r2: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918353.aspx

Comment: It's available on 2012 and so it's probably there on Windows 8, as well. No version of Windows 7 will have these even if you upgrade to Windows PowerShell 4.0. This module, and it's cmdlets, need the newer, underlying operating system and that is why they are not available in Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

"PrintManagement" module, which includes the commands you mentioned was available with PowerShell v3 on Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012
In a sense, it's tied to the Operating System, not directly to the PowerShell version.

```
    CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName                                                                         
-----------     ----                                               ----------                                                                         
Function        Add-Printer                                        printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Add-PrinterDriver                                  printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Add-PrinterPort                                    printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Get-PrintConfiguration                             printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Get-Printer                                        printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Get-PrinterDriver                                  printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Get-PrinterPort                                    printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Get-PrinterProperty                                printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Get-PrintJob                                       printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Read-PrinterNfcTag                                 printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Remove-Printer                                     printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Remove-PrinterDriver                               printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Remove-PrinterPort                                 printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Remove-PrintJob                                    printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Rename-Printer                                     printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Restart-PrintJob                                   printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Resume-PrintJob                                    printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Set-PrintConfiguration                             printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Set-Printer                                        printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Set-PrinterProperty                                printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Suspend-PrintJob                                   printmanagement                                                                    
Function        Write-PrinterNfcTag                                printmanagement
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Since these are functions, are they written in powershell script - and if I had a Win8 machine, could I copy them to my Win7 powershell path?

Answer (score -1):

PowerShell to share and unshare the printers
http://winplat.net/2015/12/04/powershell-to-share-and-unshared-the-printers/

### To share a printer

```
Set-Printer -Name DummyPrinter -Shared $True -Published $True -ShareName MyDummyPrinter
```

### To share a printer on remote computer

```
Set-Printer -Name DummyPrinter -Shared $True -Published $True -ShareName MyDummyPrinter -ComuterName PrintSvr01
```

Where,
`DummyPrinter` is the name of the print queue,
`MyDummyPrinter` is the desired shared name and
`PrintSvr01` is the remote server that hosts the printer.

Please note, the parameter `-Publish` enabled the option ‘List in Directory’. You can omit if you do not want the option.

### Multiple Printers?

`get-printer -ComputerName PrintSvr01 | foreach{Set-Printer -name $_.name -Shared $true -ShareName $_.name -Published $true -ComputerName PrintSvr01}`

### To unshare a printer

To unshare, set the –Shared parameter to $False
`Set-Printer -Name DummyPrinter -Shared $True -ComuterName PrintSvr01`